# Java Security file location on Mac Snow Leopard

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I need to move a file from my Linux machine located under `~/jdk1.6.0_03/jre/lib/security` to my Mac. Is the correct folder to place this file under `/Library/Java/Home/lib/security`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Actually it is a symbolic link that points to the correct framework, usually `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it. I have the 'java.security' and 'java.policy' files I expected to find. Give it a shot.